# What is this plywood joining mechanism and hardware for knock-down furniture?

Tags: joinery, plywood, screws, mdf

Just came across a plywood joint mechanism, which I found very interesting as new woodworker. Basically I don't know what it is called and can't find any in our local market. I am attaching the photos here:

- **Screw 1**: This is the screw which goes inside the white bit

[image]

- **Screw 2**: This screw is positioned perpendicular to **Screw 1** through a hole.

[image]

- Looks like this when **Screw 1** is put inside

[image]

Now, could anybody tell me :-
***1. What are the name of the screws.

2. What is the mechanism called.***

Comment: At least over here in Europe, these are extremely common in mass-produced flat pack furniture. A lot of stuff from Ikea is constructed in this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cam bolt and cam screw connector. Very popular in european style cabinetry.

[image]
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Crown-Bolt-15-mm-x-19-mm-Cam-Connector-Zinc-50438/203088336

[image]http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-6-mm-x-45-5-mm-Connecting-Zinc-Bolt-Cam-Screw-818238/204281642